# Django: Save inline form before run action

Tags: django, django-admin, tabular, django-admin-actions

I'm using a `django-inline-actions` package for let end-users run actions in admin inlines.
But it's no matter what exactly using for action button, i can implement it by hand (like [this](https://hakibenita.com/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin), for example), behavior will still the same.

This look as:
[image]

As provided by the django engine, the user does things like:

1. Fill inline
2. Click `Save and continue` button
3. Click action button
   [image]

and he repeating it again and again, becouse users use action buttons very often.

Is there any possibility for omit step 2?

I think, it can be javascript hook, which capture click event, save inline data with ajax, and then run action. But i have no idea how implement it.

May be there is another way to do it?